# Automate the restore process for cassandra

Tags: perl, shell, unix, cassandra

I have got 100 columnfamilies in 1 keyspace and i have got the backup (snapshot) of them and i want to restore from the backup to the new cassandra cluster. The below link says i need to delete the files for each column family and copy them. Is there any easier way to automate that such as looking for the columnfamily name in the filename and search for the folder in the keyspace and copy the files into that folder like unix  shell script. There are huge amount of files.Could you any please let me know. Thanks

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/operations/backup_restore#snapshot-loc

```
keyspace1-column_family1-ia-1362-Data.db
keyspace1-column_family1-ia-1362-compressionInfo.db
keyspace1-column_family2-ia-1362-Data.db
```